# jq: missing key in front of the value, only value is printing

Tags: json, curl, jq

This is the raw data I pull from my api:

```
{
  "observations": [
    {
      "winddir": 292,
      "humidity": 92,
      "qcStatus": 1,
      "imperial": {
        "temp": 20,
        "heatIndex": 20,
        "dewpt": 40,
        "windChill": 20,
        "windSpeed": 3, 
        "windGust": 3,
        "pressure": 29.71,
        "precipRate": 0,
        "precipTotal": 0.01,
        "elev": 1905
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the command that I run:

```
curl -s 'https://api.myawesomeapidata.com' | jq -r '.observations[].winddir, .observations[].humidity, .observations[].imperial.temp'
```

This is the output:

```
292
92
20
```

This is the output I would like:

```
Wind Direction: 292
Humidity: 92
Temperature: 20
```

But I would be fine if this were the output:

```
winddir: 292
humidity: 92
temp: 20
```

As you can see, I would like the key to appear in front of the value. Preferably allowing me to change the name of the key (Wind Direction) before printing, but I would also be fine with the original key name (winddir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using [String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo))

```sh
… | jq -r '.observations[]
  | "Wind Direction: \(.winddir)"
  , "Humidity: \(.humidity)"
  , "Temperature: \(.imperial.temp)"
'
```

```
Wind Direction: 292
Humidity: 92
Temperature: 20
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uCJH3aMH37)

Answer (score 0):

Yet you can keep *the original key names* through use of

```
jq -r '.observations[] | {winddir},{humidity},(.imperial| {temp})| "\(keys[]) : \(.[])"'
```

which results

```
winddir : 292
humidity : 92
temp : 20
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AztkjHph7z)</kbd>

Comment: You could simplify the latter part with string interpolation as well: `.observations[] | {winddir}, {humidity}, (.imperial | {temp}) | "\(keys[]): \(.[])"`.